# Am I submitting this POST body correctly using retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to use an API where one of the endpoints accepts multiple requests in a single POST body like so:

```
body:
{
  "<requestId>": {
    "actionFoo": "objId"
  },
  "<requestId>": {
    "actionBar": "objId"
  }
}
```

The requestIds are unique strings that are generated on the client side.  I am generating UUIDs for these values.

So I tried to use Retrofit using an Api defined like so:

First I defined an "ActionCommand" object:

```
public class ActionCommand {

private String actionFoo;
private String actionBar;

}
```

and fed it into a Hashmap map.  I used an api defined like this:

```
@POST("/path/{someObjectId}/commands")
Map<String,ActionResponse> sendActions(@Path("someObjectId")String objectId, @Body Map<String, ActionCommand> actionMap);
```

The backend is definitely getting the objectId properly, but not any of the actions in the map.  I'm not sure how else I should be sending these parameters

Thanks,

Comment: try whether it helps to make the properties public. Or is there a public getter for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My retrofit setup was correct.  the problem was that I left out the "application/json" header.

Answer (score 0):

Change your pojo class like this:

```
package com.example;

    import javax.annotation.Generated;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    @Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
    public class MyPojo {

    @SerializedName("<requestId>")
    @Expose
    private RequestId requestId;

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The requestId
    */
    public RequestId getRequestId() {
    return requestId;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param requestId
    * The <requestId>
    */
    public void setRequestId(RequestId requestId) {
    this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    }
```

Your Second Pojo will be like this;

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class RequestId {

@SerializedName("actionBar")
@Expose
private String actionBar;

/**
* 
* @return
* The actionBar
*/
public String getActionBar() {
return actionBar;
}

/**
* 
* @param actionBar
* The actionBar
*/
public void setActionBar(String actionBar) {
this.actionBar = actionBar;
}

}
```